# Unity Terminal Emulator Information

Tags: ubuntu, terminal-emulator, unity

Q1-->Is the Terminal Emulator in the Unity Launcher the Unity Terminal Emulator?

Q2-->If so, then what is its name?

If not,then:

3) Which Terminal Emulator does Unity use in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

4) And exactly what does the Terminal option mean in the launcher?

Comment: Individual Questions should be posted Individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers:

> Q1-->Is the Terminal Emulator in the Unity Launcher the Unity Terminal Emulator?

No, there is no "Unity Terminal Emulator".

---

> Q2-->If yes, what is its name?

Irrelevant.  Skip to next.

---

> Q3-->Which terminal Emulator does Unity use in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

`gnome-terminal` is the name of the default terminal emulator program used in (and shipped with) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  It is a separate package and is not part of Unity, so saying that Unity uses it is wrong.  (That is, you could use any of the other terminal emulators made available, but it might not show up as 'Terminal' in Unity.  It is also not integrated into Unity, it's just one piece of software, not part of Unity.)

---

> Q4-->And exactly what does the terminal option mean in the launcher?

"Terminal" is another word for the 'command line interface' in this case.  In the ancient past of computers, a "terminal" would be an input interface.  It was all command line back then.

Since then, 'Terminal' has become synonymous with an interface to the command line environment, through terminal emulators and such.

Comment: Answer updated thanks to @Gilles making the OP's question readable and legible.